# change url in codeigniter when change page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a login page creating at first the controller using codeigniter php and loading the view. When I login in the page the url .../login doesn't change in index (that is the page loaded) but remain login. how can I change in this way when I login correctly the url became /index?

Comment: read about php sessions and redirect headers. The answer is simple, but i don't think would help: use redirect('YOUR_URL_HERE');

Comment: Ok now I had finally understand what means redirect method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the login was successful, you can use `redirect('controller/method');` to redirect the user where you want.

Don't forget that to be able to use `redirect` function, you should have loaded the **url helper** in controller's `__construct()` method or in `config/autoload.php` file to call the helper in the entire application.

How to load url helper in `__construct()` function?

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); // Don't forget to call the parent constructor in this method

    // Now we can easily load our desired stuff
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

Or you can load it just after successfull login in `login()` method.

Take a look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html for more information.

Comment: But I can call only the controller? I have to call also the method inside the controller?

Comment: Are you talking about `redirect()`'s input? You can call only the controller like `redirect('user');` to redirect to `user/index` (because `index` is the default method for every controller), or you can specify both controller and method like `redirect('user/register');`